# Visual Studio 2022 Web server failed to listen on port 7189

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

The program '[25472]' has exited with code 2147516553 (0x80008089).

- I have closed and re-opened visual studio.
- I have restarted my computer.
- I have shut down my computer.
- I deleted bin and obj. Clean and Rebuild.
- I deleted .vs. Clean and Rebuild.
- I deleted the entire repo and re-pulled it down.
- I changed Ports in the debug config
- I deleted the IIS Express Configuration files
- I had a co-worked who is using VS 2022 pull the same repo down and it worked for him.

I am using .NET 6.

I am out of ideas, any and all help would be apricated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I had to go into Visual Studio Installer and repair my installation. Once that was complete, everything ran fine.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, what led me to the solution was to activate all exceptions (Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings, check all the boxes).
After that I got a proper error pointing me to a recent change in DB that was preventing my application from starting. Good luck!

Comment: Ooh - this is the only thing that helped my case.  Doing this caught the fact that a silly little change was causing my startup code in `Program.cs` to throw, which manifested itself as "web server failed to listen on port...".  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem appear after a Windows update and repairing and updating Visual Studio 2022 did not fix it and I had no idea what was going on. **My issue was that .NET 7 SDK had an update that needed to be installed.** I don't know if some people have it install automatically but I have to do it manually and that fixed the problem.

It was hard to tell because I usually run the project with `https` instead of `IIS Express` as the launch setting and it shows the "failed to listen on port 7189" error, and the browser does not open even though it is set to "launchBrowser: true". Once I switched to IIS Express the browser opened and showed the .Net version error, and then it was pretty simple to solve from there. Something like this happens every so often and I always forget to check.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

[image]

Comment: After screwing around for an hour with this problem, this was the solution. I know I experienced this at least once before, but couldn't remember what was the cause.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I run this command and see the real error in cmd:

```
dotnet run --project /projectfolder/projfile.csproj
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was with the .Net version installed, my project was running on .Net 6 and I have not installed this version kindly check which version you have installed and also the project will run if it is backward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt many devs will run into this, but this happened to me after I accidentally deleted the ***app.Run()*** command in Program.cs. Doh!